# Reflection and dynamic in-memory assemblies

Tags: c#, reflection

Let us say I create a type dynamically using CSharpCodeProvider and choose NOT to persist the results. The assembly that is generated is existing only in memory.
Let us say I Create two types in two different in-memory assemblies:

Assembly1:

```
public class DynamicTypeA { }
```

Assembly2:

```
public class DynamicTypeB
{
       public DynamicTypeA MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see the second type has a property of the first type.
Cool. Now I want to explore DynamicTypeB using reflection:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo pi in typeof(DynamicTypeB).GetProperties())
{
    Console.WriteLine(pi.PropertyType.Name);
}
```

It turns out that PropertyInfo.PropertyType fails when the assembly is not located on disk !!!
This is true for MemberInfo and for all other type investigation constructs.

As we all know lots of .Net APIs is using type investigation on the backend and they would fail when the investigated type happens to live in an in-memory assembly. For Example Expression.Bind takes a MemberInfo as the first parameter and is using it to validate that the type of the expression provided in the second parameter matches the type of the member. When this type happens to be in an in memory assembly Expression.Bind fails.

Can anyone think of a solution?

Creating types dynamically and writing them do disk pollutes the running environment and that is bad, yet without reflection these types are worthless.

Thanks
Manu

Answer (score 1):

> > It turns out that PropertyInfo.PropertyType fails when the assembly is not located on disk

Are you sure? Take a look:

```
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        string code = @"
             namespace foo {
                 public class DynamicTypeA { }
                 public class DynamicTypeB {
                     public DynamicTypeA MyProperty { get; set; } 
                 }
             }       
        ";

        CSharpCodeProvider csp = new CSharpCodeProvider();

        CompilerParameters p = new CompilerParameters();
        p.GenerateInMemory = true;

        var results = csp.CompileAssemblyFromSource( p, code );

        foreach ( Type type in results.CompiledAssembly.GetTypes() )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( type.Name );

            foreach ( PropertyInfo pi in type.GetProperties() )
            {
                Console.WriteLine( "\t{0}", pi.PropertyType.Name );
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

This uses your snippet and works like a charm.

Moving the loop to the inside of the dynamic code doesn't change much, it still works:

```
        string code = @"
             using System;
             using System.Reflection; 
             namespace foo {
                 public class DynamicTypeA { }
                 public class DynamicTypeB {
                     public DynamicTypeA MyProperty { get; set; } 
                 }

                 public class DynamicTypeC {
                     public void Foo() {
                        foreach ( PropertyInfo pi in typeof(DynamicTypeB).GetProperties() )
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine( pi.PropertyType.Name );
                        }
                     } 
                 }
             }       
        ";

        CSharpCodeProvider csp = new CSharpCodeProvider();

        CompilerParameters p = new CompilerParameters();
        p.GenerateInMemory = true;

        var results = csp.CompileAssemblyFromSource( p, code );

        var c = results.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance( "foo.DynamicTypeC" );
        var typeC = c.GetType();

        typeC.InvokeMember( "Foo", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | 
            BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, null, c, null );
```

If for some reason you have issues here, you are definitely doing something more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem:
I need to load the dynamically compiled assemblies into the current AppDomain, only then  I will be able to retrieve any info by reflection.

I would like to thank Sam Alavi for explaining this to me.
Here is the code with the necessary fix:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public Assembly AssemblyA { get; set; }
    public Assembly AssemblyB { get; set; }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        var parametersA = new CompilerParameters();
        parametersA.GenerateInMemory = true;
        parametersA.OutputAssembly = "dynamicA.dll";

        var code1 = @"namespace DynamicA {  public class DynamicClassA  {  } }";
        var result1 = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parametersA, code1);
        this.AssemblyA = result1.CompiledAssembly;

        var parametersB = new CompilerParameters();
        parametersA.GenerateInMemory = true;
        parametersB.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("dynamicA.dll");
        parametersB.OutputAssembly = "dynamicB.dll";
        var code2 = @"using DynamicA; namespace DynamicB { public class DynamicB { public DynamicClassA MyProperty { get; set; } } }";

        var results2 = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parametersB, code2);
        this.AssemblyB = results2.CompiledAssembly;

        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Name.Contains("dynamicA"))
                return this.AssemblyA;
            if (e.Name.Contains("dynamicB"))
                return this.AssemblyB;
            return null;

        };
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(this.AssemblyA.FullName);
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(this.AssemblyB.FullName);


        var t = results2.CompiledAssembly.DefinedTypes.First();
        var pi = t.GetProperty("MyProperty");

         var res = pi.PropertyType.Name;

        return View(res);
    }
}
```